# How can I block and dim everything on a page with one exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried using blockUI jQuery plugin to block the UI on a page. blockUI works fine but it seems there is no option to block everything *except* one element. I want to encourage a user to enter a value once per week so I want to block everything except the div containing a slider and input field.

I tried something like this

$('div.grid_12').not('#mydiv').block({ message: null });

but everything gets overlayed by blockUI, including #myDiv. I also tried hiking the z-index on  #myDiv. This created problems with the jqueryUI slider which has its own z-index requirements. Unblocking #myDiv also has no effect. What I basically want is the *reverse* of this : http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Does anyone know a solid way of doing this? Perhaps I could clone the div and overlay it somehow?

Comment: Did you try: $('div.grid_12:not(#mydiv)').block({ message: null });

Comment: yes - doesn't work either. The issue (i think) is that blockUI overlays a div on top of everything below div.grid_12 in the dom tree.  I think that it just isn't designed to do what I want so I will need to find another way.

Comment: Or just try giving #mydiv a z-index of higher than 1000 and position relative; eg: `<div id="mydiv" style="z-index:9999; position:relative;"></div>`

Comment: yep that was it - just figured this out and came back to find your comment. It was the position:relative that I was missing. If you add an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, and thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following code:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="z-index:9999; position:relative;"></div>
```

Will override the z-index of the block, meaning your div will appear above it.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried the z-index but forgotten that I needed to specify position for it to work. blockUI puts things just above 1000 so I went with 1100